# Plotting 'Hi' in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I wished to plot this ['Hi'](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=19), which may be '[Hello World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world)' graphical equivalent in MATLAB. Haven't been able to do it. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link from 'Hi'. Deleted the answer.

Comment: `meshgrid` and `mesh` ? I am lost to where you were not able to do it.

Comment: @phwd : I was trying with plot3 ..... and nothing seemed to yield !

Comment: @yuk, @Amro : Many thanks guys ! ..... Can we do a 'HELLO WORLD' .... that would be some ask ! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a code for the plot using the formula on the linked page and specified axis limits. You can play with colormap, view direction and other properties to get closer.

```
x = linspace(-3,3,50);
y = linspace(-5,5,50);
[X Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z = exp(-X.^2-Y.^2/2).*cos(4*X) + exp(-3*((X+0.5).^2+Y.^2/2));
Z(Z>0.001)=0.001;
Z(Z<-0.001)=-0.001;
surf(X,Y,Z);
colormap(flipud(cool))
view([1 -1.5 2])
```

[image: cool MATLAB screenshot]

Answer (score 14):

It seems @yuk beat me to it, still this is my version:

```
[x y] = meshgrid( linspace(-3,3,50), linspace(-5,5,50) );
z = exp(-x.^2-0.5*y.^2).*cos(4*x) + exp(-3*((x+0.5).^2+0.5*y.^2));
idx = ( abs(z)>0.001 );
z(idx) = 0.001 * sign(z(idx));

figure('renderer','opengl')
patch(surf2patch(surf(x,y,z)), 'FaceColor','interp');
set(gca, 'Box','on', ...
    'XColor',[.3 .3 .3], 'YColor',[.3 .3 .3], 'ZColor',[.3 .3 .3], 'FontSize',8)
title('$e^{-x^2 - \frac{y^2}{2}}\cos(4x) + e^{-3((x+0.5)^2+\frac{y^2}{2})}$', ...
    'Interpreter','latex', 'FontSize',12)

view(35,65)
colormap( [flipud(cool);cool] )
camlight headlight, lighting phong
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Great job, looks awesome ! If only I could choose 2 Answers ! :)